# DateAdd with a format date in a variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I was trying to concat a date in a URL with a specific format, but I need to add 1 day to the date that already exist in data extension.

```
VAR @sd, @formatSd, @date_plus1

set @sd = AttributeValue("fecha_salida")

set @formatSd = FormatDate(@sd, "dd/MM/yy")
```

at this point the script works, but when I try to use the function DateAdd like this it is not working:

```
set @date_plus1 = Format(DateAdd(@sd, "1", "D"), "dd/MM/yy")
```

What I'm doing wrong?
I'm working in cloudpages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it in a different order, like in the example below - first the DateAdd, then Format:

```
%%[ 
VAR @futureDate, @today 
SET @today = Now(1) 
SET @futureDate = DateAdd(@today, 11, "D") 
]%%
Date: %%=Format(@futureDate, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%
```

Your updated script should also work, so check if the date field is set to 'Date' data type in your Data Extension:

```
%%[
set @sd = AttributeValue('Date')
set @date_plus1 = Format(DateAdd(@sd, "1", "D"), "dd/MM/yy")
]%%

@sd: %%=v(@sd)=%%
<br>
@date_plus1: %%=v(@date_plus1)=%%
<br>
```

It resolves to:

> @sd: 8/21/2019 12:00:00 AM
>   @date_plus1: 22/08/19

Comment: Thank you @CodeRage.
 I am trying with this  and take me to an error 500, but when I use “Now” value, it works
`code`
set @date_plus1 = Format(DateAdd(Now(true), "1", "D"), "dd/MM/yy")
`code`
I also need to concat data in an URL, I’m trying with
set @link = Concat(@url,@date_plus1,@utm)

I have already checked the field type and it is correct.

Before I was using FormatDate with no problem to achieve the correct format for the URL,

set @formatSd = FormatDate(@sd, "dd/MM/yy")

 but now I need to add 1 day to that date

Comment: Most likely you get the 500 because you’re not passing a paremeter correctly. You need to test against a subscriber, and if you are querying “fecha_salida” it needs to be passed correctly to the CloudPage.

Comment: Thanks, I've test an email with subscriber data an it works